# Correct preposition in a cover letter -- "employment ...with/by/at/in... a manufacturer"

Tags: prepositions

Are the prepositions in following sentence correct?

> As a highly motivated person in the field of inorganic chemistry I'm looking for an employment **with** a Swiss manufacturer of established batteries.

I have some doubt if the proposition "with" is correctly chosen.

Here the alternatives:

- > employment **by** a Swiss manufacturer
- > employment **at** a Swiss manufacturer
- > employment **in** a Swiss manufacturer

Comment: If the cover letter to a particular company, why use "a Swiss manufacturer" at all?  Say that you're looking for a position in *their* company.  Let *them* ask you why it is.  As to your question, "with" is good, "at" is also OK.  I'd not use "by" or "in".

Comment: Concerning your comment on "a Swiss manufacturer", I wrote in the following sentence: At your company's website I appreciate your long history and therefore being market leader of traction batteries with a high standard of quality. Does this sound fine?

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd recommend lang-8.com for proofreading purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"With" is the best choice. However, you should remove "an" before "employment".

> As a highly motivated person... I'm looking for employment with a Swiss...

Further, I don't understand what "established batteries" are. Perhaps it's a term of art in your field. If not, did you mean "an established Swiss manufacturer of batteries"?

Comment: Probably the word reliable would be better than established.

Comment: Mmm... who wants to work for a company that makes unreliable batteries?